# Excel formula multiplies money based on a price range but I cannot show the cents for some cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a base price for a product. The 3 columns on the left are based on the middle column, "Discount". The Discount column uses the forumula (EX:$23): **="$"& (N27+(N27*Price!B24))& " per sq. ft."**

N27 = $23.00

Price!B24 = A dropdown list range from 0% to 100%

**Question**: How can I get it so cell, N27 - $23 show as **$23.00 per sq. ft.**

[image: Excel Formula]

I have the cells set to currency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use TEXT:

```
="$"& TEXT(N27+(N27*Price!B24),"#,##0.00") & " per sq. ft."
```

Or

```
=TEXT(N27+(N27*Price!B24),"$#,###.00 p\e\r \sq\. ft\.")
```

Comment: What does it mean when it says, "You've entered too few arguments for this function"? I get this when I use TEXT.

Comment: Sorry, copied too many `)`  see edit